# How to increment an IP address based on a former line?

Tags: excel, vba, increment

First of all I'm a total VBA scrub. I am learning since we use a lot of excel at work, and usually the sheets are just basic with no smarts to them whatsoever. I am trying to make a simple macro which creates a new row at the top of the sheet and then fills it with some blanks and some informations based on the earlier lines. So far it has been going fine, but I am now at a point where I want it to fill in the next IP in line, which it should read from the former line. This is my code so far, and I'm struggling on what to fill in after Range("G2").Value = in order to make it increment the IP fround in G3.

```
Sub newloc()
Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
Range("D2").Value = "Odense C"
Range("F2").Formula = "=F3 + 1"
Range("G2").Value =
Range("H2").Formula = "=H3 + 1"

End Sub
```

As you can see the code is super simple, and as I don't understand much about VBA scripting yet, please come with nice and simple answers. Preferably something I can copy paste, and then explanations to the functions so I can understand why it suddenly works.

Comment: Please provide your worksheet screenshot to clearly understand your question

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/H1TgP

Comment: You'll probably have to create a function that will check the max IP range you can go to. Wouldn't you also have to increment by more than just 1 sometimes? Seems to be a bit more complex than just adding 1 like you have for columns F & H

Comment: Actually this one just has to increment by 8, but thats a continuous factor for the entire thing, so I had in mind to just fix that myself after seeing how its done overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. It counts up to 254 and then does "+1" on the next.

```
Sub newloc()
    Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
    Range("D2").Value = "Odense C"
    Range("F2").Formula = "=F3 + 1"
    Range("H2").Formula = "=H3 + 1"

    Arr = Split(Range("G3").Value, ".")
    If Arr(3) = 254 Then
        Arr(3) = 1
        If Arr(2) < 254 Then
            Arr(2) = Arr(2) + 1
        Else
            Arr(2) = 1
            If Arr(1) < 254 Then
                Arr(1) = Arr(1) + 1
            Else
                Arr(1) = 1
                If Arr(0) < 254 Then
                    Arr(0) = Arr(0) + 1
                Else
                    MsgBox "Error! No more IP's available"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        Arr(3) = Arr(3) + 1
    End If

    Range("G2").Value = Join(Arr, ".")


End Sub
```

[image]

In the image above I have edited the cells to simulate a larger range.

Answer (score 0):

CHANGED!

Put this function:

```
Function getNextIp(getIp As String) As String
Dim numArr As Variant
numArr = Split(getIp, ".")
If numArr(3) = 255 Then
    If numArr(2) = 255 Then
        If numArr(1) = 255 Then
            getNextIp = (numArr(0) + 1) & "." & "1" & "." & "1" & "." & "1"
        Else
            getNextIp = numArr(0) & "." & (numArr(1) + 1) & "." & "1" & "." & "1"
        End If
    Else
            getNextIp = numArr(0) & "." & numArr(1) & "." & (numArr(2) + 1) & "." & "1"
    End If
Else
            getNextIp = numArr(0) & "." & numArr(1) & "." & numArr(2) & "." & (numArr(3) + 1)
End If
End Function
```

After that your code will be like this:

```
Dim IpText As String
Sub newloc()
   Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
   Range("D2").Value = "Odense C"
   Range("F2").Formula = "=F3 + 1"
   IpText = Range("G3").Value
   Range("G2").Value = getNextIp(IpText)
   Range("H2").Formula = "=H3 + 1"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why using a global variable?

Comment: this is a great start, but it kinda gets ruined when the IP reachers 255, as instead of being 255 it should increment the next octet by 1 instead. Any possible addition to counter that problem?

Answer (score 0):

**edited** after OP?s further specifications

you may want to use this function:

```
Optiion Explicit

Function GetNextIPAddress(baseIP As String) As String
    Dim numbersArr As Variant
    Dim iPos As Long, iNum As Long

    numbersArr = Split(baseIP, ".") '<--| get all numbers delimited by a "." from passed string into an array
    For iNum = UBound(numbersArr) To 0 Step -1
        If numbersArr(iNum) <> "254" Then Exit For
    Next iNum

    If iNum = -1 Then
        GetNextIPAddress = "Error"
    Else
        iPos = InStrRev(baseIP, numbersArr(iNum))
        GetNextIPAddress = Left(baseIP, iPos - 1) & numbersArr(iNum) + 1 & Right(baseIP, Len(baseIP) - (iPos + Len(numbersArr(iNum))) + 1)
    End If
End Function
```

to be exploited in your mnain code as follows

```
Range("G2").Value = GetNextIPAddress(Range("G3").Value)
```

Comment: This looked very promising, but it might just be my lack of VB knowledge, but it only generates a runtime error 13 "type mismatch" I'm betting its a simple mistake on my behalf. I just put the function outside of the sub in the start of the module nad the added the range("G2") line inside the sub

Comment: 1) put the whole Function code (from `Function GetNextIPAddress(baseIP As String) As String` to `End Function`, these included) in any module and outside any other Function or Sub 2) use it in any other Sub code by means of such statements as `someRange.Value = GetNextIPAddress(someOtherRange.Value)`, where both `someRange` and `someOtherRange` must be valid range references

Comment: Well it works now but same problem as with @bzimor 's post it does not increment the next octet after 254. I need some help here for the max number to be 254, and then it will increment the next octet instead of just keep going up in the last octet.

Comment: Well, then as per this site rules you should mark answer as accepted, since it solved your _original_ question, that didn't mention any "254" issue. Anyhow see edited post. But remember, accept/don't accept answers if they do/don't solve your question as you _originally_ posted it. While should new issues arise (quite common), make a new post

Comment: @user3598756 He did say IP. It's common knowledge that IPs run in the 1->255 range (don't know why he want's 254). And please link to those rules.

Comment: @Andreas, maybe it's a "common knowledge" of yours but not of mine, since I don't deal with nor bother IP's. To avoid issues about what could be of "common knowledge", question must be clear. Anyhow I had edited my post as well

Comment: @user3598756 OK. Common knowledge or not, don't get all grumpy about it. I'd say that most of the times you need to correct something on an answer due to incomplete questions. Still waiting for that link.

Comment: @Andreas, without even knowing what "grumpy" means  I can say I'm not getting it! As you saw I gave that advice and at the same time I updated my code to follow the new need. As for the link, I've read it once and then seen it reminded around here many times: I guess that [taking a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) would do